# How to copy Sites and Favorites when reinstalling Harmon.it for Outlook

Tags: outlook, harmon.ie

I am reinstalling Harmon.ie for Outlook on a new PC and would like to import the Sites and Favorites from the old PC.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Would copying some registry key an option?

Thank you in advance,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

Mario,

If you are customer, please report your issues and/or questions to support@harmon.ie

harmon.ie can share user’s site and favorites between devices – including mobile and desktop – as detailed in harmon.ie User Guide Sharing sites between harmon.ie clients.

If you are looking to copy user settings, including their sites and favorites, from one workstation to another you can do that by exporting registry and preferences file from one workstation and copying them to their corresponding locations to the new workstation
•   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs]
•   %APPDATA%\Mainsoft\Harmony.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.prefs

Note that recent Harmon.ie option also offers the option to “Share sites and Favorites …”, when this option set the sites and Favorites will be saved inside your social server and will be synced back when you define the corresponding social server (new installation for instance)